# Banner Student Self-Service SIS Framework Alternatives

Tags: gratis, open-source, php, educational

I'm interested in a college student information service framework, like [Banner](https://www3.aucegypt.edu/sso/bannerSupport/) to support students admission, enrolment in departments, selecting/adding/dropping/withdrawing courses, fees and tuition billing system, teaching staff and administration staff normal tasks.

I'm searching for something that is free / open source in PHP and can be customised to specific admission and enrolment rules and the college bylaw(s). Also if this SIS system can be integrated with the [Moodle](https://moodle.org/) LMS system.